# Is there a non-negative finite measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-compact metric space $X$ s.t. $\int_X f d \mu >0$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Is there a non-negative finite measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-compact metric space $X$ s.t. for any $f \in C_c(X), f \geq 0, f \not\equiv 0$ we have $\int_X f d \mu >0$?

I think it is right, but I have no idea to construct such a measure.

I have tried to consider the condition "$\sigma$-compact", which means $X= \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n$ for $K_n$ compact. Note that $X$ is a metric space. I wanted to construct such a measure by $\rho(x,K_n)$.

I am stuck here.

Comment: what about $\mu$ in $X:=\{0\}$ and $\mu(\{0\})=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a dense set $\{x_n\}_n$ in $X$ and let
$$
  \mu = \sum_n {\delta_{x_n}\over 2^n},
  $$
where the *Dirac* measure $\delta_{x}$ is defined by $\delta_{x}(E)=0$ or $1$, acccording to whether $x\in E$ or not.